# Does Pythagorean law holds in Hilbert space or plane?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Does Pythagorean law holds in Hilbert space or plane?

I know that Pythagorean law holds in Euclidean plane while Hilbert space is a generalisation of Euclidean space.

I know that finite orthonormal set $S$ in a hilbert space $H$, then Pythagorean law holds.

Can someone explain it elaborately whether Pythagorean law holds in Hilbert plane.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal elements of any inner product space then $\|x+y\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S= \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a finite orthogonal set in an inner product space. We have
$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\|^2 = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x_i, x_j\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i\|^2\delta_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2$$
which is the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: Sir, I saw for finite orthonormal set it holds.  My question whether Pythagorean law holds in Hilbert space or not.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR It holds in arbitrary inner product spaces so in particular it holds in Hilbert spaces, yes.

Comment: Sir, Ok, then why we are using the restriction of finite orthogonal set ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Because for arbitrary orthogonal sets $\{x_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ the sum $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} x_\lambda$ need not converge. If it does converge, then the same proof as above yields that $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \|x_\lambda\|^2 < +\infty$ and $$\left\|\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} x_\lambda\right\|^2 = \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \|x_\lambda\|^2$$
You also need to use continuity of the inner product for this.

Comment: Sir, great answer from you. I verified from Wikipadea also. Now my question is what is the difference between Hilbert space and Hilbert plane? Secondly, Does Pythagorean theorem holds in Hilbert plane also ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR If I'm not mistaken, Hilbert plane is simply the standard Euclidean plane founded by [David Hilbert's axioms from $1899$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms). So the Pythagorean theorem certainly holds there. On the other hand, a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is a complete inner product space, which is completely abstract. But, as we showed above, what we call the Pythagorean theorem still holds.

Comment: Sir, ok nice. So Hilbert;s axioms is included in Hilbert space. Is not it?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Not really, a Hilbert space is something much more abstract and general. Besides, a Hilbert space doesn't have to be two-dimensional like the Euclidean plane. And it can be over the field $\mathbb{C}$, not only $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: very nice sir. I got it. My last request to you- Can you give an example of Hilbert Space which does not satisfy Hilbert's axiom?   For example $L[a,b]$, the set of all square integrable functions on $[a,b]$ is a Hilbert Space. How to show that this space does not hold Hilbert's axiom?  or Any other counter-example.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Well, $L^2[a,b]$ is an infinite-dimensional space so in particular, it cannot be a plane. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903235/144766) discusses that Hilbert spaces are actually direct generalizations of the Euclidean plane to $n$ dimensions, or even infinite dimensions. Otherwise, I'm not sure.

Comment: ok , You helped a lot. If you in future think about a counter-example, then you may include it here. Again a lot thanks to help me